# Trimming input boxes and adding to context JSTL

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm new to the JSTL world so please be gentle with me, I already been reading but couldn't find the solution for this.

I want to trim the whitespaces from both beginning and end of a input box, so when the user click the submit button my Controller receives the string without spaces.

Please don't suggest me to use other frameworks because I'm already having trouble with this, when I master this, I'll advance to the next step.

Here's my JSP code, I tried this, but doesn't work, it seems that the context doesn't keep the values I pass, after that I was only trying...  Any help appreciated!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="resources/index-style.css" TYPE="text/css">
<title>Submit a new academic!</title>
</head>
<div class="home">
    <a href="index"><img src="resources/home.png" /></a>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <h1>This is the place where you register a new Academic on the
        system!</h1>
</div>
<p></p>

<div class="list">
    <form action="addAcademicAction" method="post">
        <p>Submit your name:</p>
        <input type="text" name="academicName"><br>
        <p>Level of education</p>
        <input type="radio" name="educationLevel" value="student" checked>Student<br>
        <input type="radio" name="educationLevel" value="csstudent">Computer
        Science Student<br> <input type="radio" name="educationLevel"
            value="professor">Professor<br> <br>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" value="HTML">Add
            Academic!</button>
    </form>
</div>

<c:if test="${context.request.method=='POST'}">
    <c:set var="academicName" value="${fn:trim(param.academicName)}"/>
</c:if>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is that hard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to understand how a JSP works. A JSP is executed at server-side. It's simply another way to write a servlet. Its goal is to generate HTML, which will be sent to the browser.

The `<c:set>` tag is used to set a page-scope attribute. You can see that as a variable that is local to the current JSP execution. So the above is more or less equivalent to this:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
...
out.println("</div>");
String academicName = null;
if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
    academicName = request.getParameter("academicName").trim();
}
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
```

So, in clear, you're defining a local variable, which is never used.

If you want to trim what is submitted by the form generated by the JSP, it's not this JSP that must trim the parameter, it's the Spring controller which will receive the form submission, and which is thus mapped to the path "addAcademicAction".

Comment: Alright man, thanks. I'll keep on reading. But first I have to get this done. I guess I'll have to trim my inputs in my Controller, too bad the trim() method of the String class removes all whitespaces...